# Elasticsearch 7.13 - elastic search response with old data after update api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

We using elastic 7.13
we are doing periodical update to index using upsert

The sequence of operations

1. create new index with dynamic mapping `all strings mapped as text`

   ```
    "dynamic_templates": [
    {
      "strings_as_keywords": {
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "search_term_analyzer",
          "copy_to": "_all",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   ```

   ]
2. upsert bulk with the attached code (I don't have equivalent with rest)
3. doing search on specific filed

   ```
   localhost:9200/mdsearch-vitaly123/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "fullyQualifiedName": `value_test`
        }
      }
    }
   ```
4. got 1 result
5. upsert again now "fullyQualifiedName": "value_test1234" (as in step 2)
6. do search as in step 3
7. got 2 results 1 doc  with  "fullyQualifiedName": "value_test"
   and other  "fullyQualifiedName": "value_test1234"

snippet below of upsert (step 2):

```
@Override
    public List<BulkItemStatus> updateDocumentBulk(String indexName, List<JsonObject> indexDocuments) throws MDSearchIndexerException {
        BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest().setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE);
        ofNullable(indexDocuments).orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new)
                .forEach(x -> {
                var id = x.get("_id").getAsString();
                x.remove("_id");
                    request.add(new UpdateRequest(indexName, id)
                            .docAsUpsert(true)
                            .doc(x.toString(), XContentType.JSON)
                            .retryOnConflict(3)
                    );
                });
        BulkResponse bulk = elasticsearchRestClient.bulk(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return stream(bulk.getItems())
                .map(r -> new BulkItemStatus(r.getId(), isSuccess(r), r.getFailureMessage()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I can search by updated properties.

But the problem is that searches retrieve "updated fields" and previous one as well.

How can I solve it ?
maybe limit somehow the version number to be only 1.

I set `setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE)` but it didn't helped

**Here in picture we can see result**

[image]

P.S - old and updated data retrieved as well

Suggestions ?

Regards,

Comment: When you update a document, the version will always increase and when you retrieve the document you retrieve the content of the actual document, the previous document is gone forever. So I'm not sure what you mean by "old data". ES doesn't keep multiple versions of a given document, only the last version. Maybe show us a sequence (get, update, get) and what doesn't seem right to you?

Comment: @Val  - I've updated my question

Comment: Can you open the two hits you get please? They must have different IDs, which means you're not doing any updates but simply an insert with a new ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that the following line must yield `null`:

```
var id = x.get("_id").getAsString();
```

In other words, there is no `_id` field in the JSON documents you pass in `indexDocuments`. It is not allowed to have fields with an initial underscore character in the source documents. If it was the case, you'd get the following error:

> Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters.

Hence, your update request cannot update any document (since there's no ID to identify the document to update) and will simply insert a new one (i.e. what `docAsUpsert` does), which is why you're seeing two different documents.

Comment: Yes I have different doc id's in response. I'm trying to see if I have null IDs as you said. Basically i'm taking them from DB, and I don't think it could be

Comment: I think you're not getting the ID the right way. Try to dump the JSON document and you'll see. Please show the two hits you're getting and we'll see how it looks.

Comment: Think you are right, I'm getting different id from outside and ES upsert it as new

Comment: That's the only explanation, if you manage to find the right field for the ID, then your code will work as you expect.